# FME Loop: Many to many connection

Tags: fme-form, loop

I have two tables with lines.

- The 1st table has an attribute end_point
- The 2nd table has an attribute start_point

I want to join the first table with the second table (end_point = start_point).
It is a many to many connection. That's why I created a custom transformer but it's not correct.

First I created 2 lists from the 2 tables and then as you can see below I tried to create a loop with an index.

Problems:

1. I am sending the first element of the first list and the whole list of the second table to the FeatureMerger and then I am using a Tester to check when the LoopCounter becomes equal with the loopcount but it seems that the loop doesn't continue to the second element of the list.
2. I am using an AttributeManager to create a table (Append) with all the joined data but I do not think that it is the same as an append and I don't know how I can send the results as Output.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the workflow - I would use the feature holder http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/featureholder.htm and when all features are processed will move to the next transformer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mapperz. I managed to make it work and I am passing the results to a feature holder before exporting. I am going to post the full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have got your custom transformer to work, but I can't help but feel that there are more efficient ways to get the same result.

For example, you can create a many:many join using the FeatureMerger or FeatureJoiner transformers.

In the FeatureMerger you would check the boxes labelled Process Duplicate Suppliers and Generate List:

[image]

Now you have your multiple joins defined as a list. If you want to separate them out into separate features, just use a ListExploder transformer on the output.

In the FeatureJoiner you don't need to check any boxes or define a list. The transformer by default automatically carries out a many:many join and outputs one feature for each join.

If you have a large number of features to process, I would try one of these methods, because it would be orders of magnitude quicker than a looping transformer.

But do let me know if I've misunderstood your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mark ! I tested both tools and they are giving me exactly the results I need and they are way more simple than my solution!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the mistake. Here is the solution.

1. I am creating lists (one with the end points and one with the start points) and I am sending them to the custom transformer as Inputs
   [image]
2. The custom transformer looks like this now.

I am using an ExpressionEvaluator to increase the counter by 1 each time and then with a tester I am testing if the counter reached the maximum number of loops.
If not it returns to the list and fetches the next row. Otherwise the loop stops.

This documentation https://s3.amazonaws.com/gitbook/Desktop-Advanced-2019/DesktopAdvanced5CustomTransformers/5.Exercise6.html and the comment of @Mapperz were very helpful.

[image]